# Collapse one AppBar and show another AppBar at the same time on scroll in Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, appbar

I have `Header.js` component. Inside it, I have two AppBar, first AppBar is sticky, and the second is not. By default, only second AppBar showed. When we scroll, I want the second AppBar to collapse and the first AppBar to show stickied in the top of the screen.

I have seen `useScrollTrigger()` from Material-ui documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#scrolling), but it only show to hide AppBar on scroll.

```
// Header.js
import React from "react";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h6">First AppBar</Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography variant="h6">Second AppBar</Typography>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is my sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-goodall-ofvqf?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems run like you want. I used material-ui [demo](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#scrolling)

```
import React from "react";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import useScrollTrigger from '@material-ui/core/useScrollTrigger';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';

function HideOnScroll(props) {
  const { children, window } = props;
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({ target: window ? window() : undefined });

  return (
    <Slide appear={false} direction="down" in={!trigger}>
      {children}
    </Slide>
  );
}

function ElevationScroll(props) {
  const { children, window } = props;
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: 0,
    target: window ? window() : undefined,
  });

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    elevation: trigger ? 4 : 0,
  });
}


export default function Header(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <ElevationScroll  {...props}>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6">First AppBar</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      </ElevationScroll >
      {/* second appbar */}
      <HideOnScroll {...props}>
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6">Second AppBar</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      </HideOnScroll>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I copy your code to my sandbox but It doesn't seem to work as I expected. It showed both appbars since the start, and when I scroll, my second appbar collapse leaving my first appbar to show. I don't want first appbar to show since the start (I want only second appbar), but when I scroll, the second appbar must collapse and the first appbar got displayed. Basically, the first appbar sort of replace the second appbar if we scroll.

Comment: Then you could try elevation option. I've edited the code. Initially only 2nd appbar is displayed, on scroll it is hidden and 1st appbar is displayed.